# IBM WebSphere Liberty with oracle sdk

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have used oracle java and IBM java to run WebSphere Liberty profile,
And I connect with JMX but, oracle list all the MBean and IBM list two,three MBeans only. I include the monitor-1.0 in server.xml,
What changes i have to do but I need to run server with IBM build in java.

Comment: can you provide more detail such as what MBeans are seen on Oracle JDK and not on IBM JDK?  Note that some MBeans are JDK specific.  But if you are looking for Liberty MBeans (e.g. ServerInfoMBean) then it should be present on both JDKs.

Comment: This objects are found in Oracle Java. WebSphere:type=ThreadPoolStats,name=Default Executor
WebSphere:service=com.ibm.websphere.application.ApplicationMBean,name=*
WebSphere:feature=wasJmsServer,type=Queue,name=*
WebSphere:feature=wasJmsServer,type=Topic,name=*
WebSphere:name=*,j2eeType=J2EEServer